# Most efficient way to check if file extension ends in this OR that?

Tags: arrays, file, powershell, powershell-2.0, get-childitem

I had this code which I was really happy with:

```
$jpgExtensionFiles = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

$AllDrives = Get-PSDrive
  foreach ($Drive in $AllDrives) {
      $Dirs = Get-ChildItem $Drive.Root -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
      $jpgExtensionFiles.Add(($Dirs | where {$_.extension -eq ".jpg"}))         
   }
```

But now, I want to do the same thing for an array called `$bmpExtensionFiles`. I can't figure out how to do the following:

1. If the extension is .jpg, add to the first array
2. If the extension is .bmp, add to the second array

... all in one loop, for efficiency's sake. I know I can just add `$bmpExtensionFiles.Add(($Dirs | where {$_.extension -eq ".bmp"}))`, but is there a more efficient way? I would need this compatible with PowerShell v2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a switch statement, then if you want to add further types later it's easy to expand:

```
ForEach ($Dir in $Dirs)
{
    Switch ($Dir.Extension)
    {
        ".jpg" {$jpgExtensionFiles.Add($Dir)}
        ".bmp" {$bmpExtensionFiles.Add($Dir)}
    }
}
```

Comment: This works! Could you briefly explain the performance implications of doing a `foreach` with a nested `switch` as opposed to the `where` keyword I used in my example?

Comment: In your example when you pipe `$Dirs` to `where` it is effectively a nested loop (each object in the `$dirs` array is passed through the pipeline to `where`). If you added a second line for `.bmp` as per your original question, it would process the entire array twice. Using switch inside foreach means no matter how many extensions you check for, it only loops through the array once.

Comment: Perfect, exactly as I thought. Thank you for your confirmation!

Comment: I would use an array of list indexed by extension instead. No need for "if" or "switch", then.

Comment: @DavidBrabant Could you provide this solution so I can see? And could you then explain why a hash table as you describe would be more efficient?

Answer (score 1):

Not tested extensively, but should be very efficient.

```
$jpgExtensionFiles,$bmpExtensionfiles = (Get-ChildItem $Drive.Root -Recurse -include *.jpg,*.bmp -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).where({$_.extension -eq '.jpg'},'split')
```

Comment: Is this more efficient than the other answer? Can you explain what is happening?

Comment: Also, I tested your answer,  and all the files seem to go into the `$bmpExtensionfiles` array.

Comment: It should be.  It's doing early filtering, rather than the late filtering of the other solution.  The  .where() method was added in V4, and a good explanation can be found here: https://mcpmag.com/articles/2015/12/02/where-method-in-powershell.aspx.  I tested this against the C drive on my local system and got the expected results.

Comment: Ah, I'm looking for a V2 compatible solution.

Answer (score 0):

The following are **hashtable-based solutions** that **generalize to any number of extensions**:

---

#### *Multi*-pass solution using `Get-ChildItem -Filter`:

```
# Initialize a hashtable for all extexnsions of interest:
# Key is the extension name, value is an array list to be filled
# with the files ([System.IO.FileInfo] instances) having that extension.
$htFilesByType = @{ 
  '.jpg' = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
  '.bmp' = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList 
}

# Get the list of all filesystem PS drives.
$AllFsDrives = Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem

# Loop over all filesystem drives.
foreach ($Drive in $AllFsDrives) {
  # Loop over all extensions and add files with that extension to the hashtable.
  foreach ($ext in $htFilesByType.Keys) {
    # Get all files with the extension at hand at once and add them
    # to the relevant hashtable entry.
    # Note: The .Add() method returns a value, which we're not interested in,
    #       hence the `$null = ...`.
    $null = $htFilesByType[$ext].Add(
      (Get-ChildItem -Filter "*$ext" $Drive.Root -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
    )
  }
}

# Output the filled hashtable.
$htFilesByType
```

Note: At first glance, running `Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter <ext>` for *each* extension seems inefficient, but for *small* numbers of extension this may still be faster than the single-pass `Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include <ext1>, <ext2>, ...` solution below:

- The `-Filter` parameter is drive-provider-native and filters at the *source*, which makes it much more efficient than the `-Include` parameter.
- Unfortunately, though, `-Filter` only supports a *single* filter (wildcard expression such as `*.jpg`), which is why multiple passes are needed.

Also note that, for simplicity, the entire array of matching files is gathered first in each pass, and then added as a whole to the hashtable. This is fast, but also memory-consuming; if that is a concern, process the files one by one, as in the single-pass solution below.

It's **hard to predict the exact point at which a single-pass solution becomes faster**, as many factors are involved (ratio of matching files to non-matching files, number of passes, ...).
Use `Measure-Command` to compare the two solutions, when in doubt.

---

#### *Single*-pass solution using a multi-filter `Get-ChildItem -Include` command:

```
# Construct the array of wildcard expressions to use with -Include;
# e.g., @( '*.jpg', '*.bmp' )
$includes = $htFilesByType.keys -replace '^', '*'

foreach ($Drive in $AllFsDrives) {
  # Look for files with any of the extensions of interest.
  Get-ChildItem -Include $includes $Drive.Root -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    ForEach-Object {
      # Add to the appropriate array list based on the matching file's extension. 
      $null = $htFilesByType[$_.Extension].Add($_)
    }
}
```

---

Note: In PSv3 or higher, you can increase the efficiency of the `Get-ChildItem` commands slightly by adding the `-File` switch to limit matching to files only.